# appengine: NeedIndexError: The built-in indices are not efficient enough for this query and your data. Please add a composite index for this query

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

While using django.core.paginator import ObjectPaginator, I'm getting this error:

> NeedIndexError: The built-in indices
>   are not efficient enough for this
>   query and your data. Please add a
>   composite index for this query.

The original query is written in this form:

```
query = models.Cdr.all()
query.filter("var1 =", var1 )
query.filter("var2 =", var2)
query.filter("var3 =", var3)
```

I get this exception when ObjectPaginator tries to count the number of elements, but only for some values of *var1*.

Why would this query fail for some values of *var1*, while working with others?

What would you recommend for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general procedure recommended to fix `NeedIndexError` occurrences is [this one](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/msg/36bf21bab219c376). I expect the composite index may not have been built on your development depending on the amount and structure of the data (which can change depending on `var1` value) but turns out to be needed (to avoid aborting the query for efficiency reasons, as the error msg hints and Nick confirms in this comment) when running on the actual store.

Comment: If the error message given occurs, it's because it's aborting early due to inefficiency, not due to the 1000 result limit.

Comment: From the mentioned post: 'I used the following procedure to get things working, but didn't check along the way to see which of the following steps fixed things.' Not really an answer, especially when appcfg.py seems to want to involve changing things on the production app server!

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this problem. The problem is not with your code but with GAE's indexing system itself. To fix it, you have to explicitly write the index in your index.yaml file. That worked for me, but I have [read elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025018/appengine-backreferences-need-composite-index) that explicitly defining your index may not always fix it. Regardless, I recommend that you [star the bug I opened](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5185).

GAE does not automatically build an index for queries that only have equality filters. Instead, it uses an algorithm Google calls "zigzag merge join" (Google it). It appears that this algorithm is breaking down in certain situations. It looks like team google [is working on](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/94d7e74a2e882b4b) fixing this problem, but it still pops up in some situations.